# Problem in google chart api for line graph

Tags: google-visualization

> http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:131,123,126,124,122,121&chbh=a&chs=250x200&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|28/03|27/03|26/03|25/03|24/03|23/03|1:|0|100|200

I am using the above URL but it doesn't give proper output. What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use chds parameter for specifying the scale. I added chds=0,200

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chd=t:131,123,126,124,122,121&chbh=a&chs=250x200&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|28/03|27/03|26/03|25/03|24/03|23/03|1:|0|100|200&chds=0,200